# PHP and MYSQL AJAX - autofill multiple text fields

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using the great tutorial provided by Nodstrum. I am attempting to autofill multiple text fields with PHP, MYSQL, and AJAX. I have a PHP script, here is the line of code returning my results:

```
echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->name.'|'.$result->id.'\');">'.$result->name.'</li>';
```

Notice that I am seperating my results with a pipestem character.

Here is the function where I am receiving the error 'Undefined or not an object' I am breaking out the values and using the pipestem as splitting the values from mysql.

```
function fill(thisValue) {
    myvalues=thisValue.split('|') {
        $('#inputString').val(myvalues[0]);
        $('#email').val(myvalues[1]);
    }
    window.setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
```

If I 'ok' the error messages, I will eventually see both values displayed in the text fields, so I believe I am retreiving the values properly from MySQL.  I appreciate any help anyone can provide to get me steered in the right direction, or a fresh perspective.
Thanks Again,
--Matt

Comment: syntax error - myValues = thisValue.split... this line should begin with var and end with a semicolon and get rid of the curly brackets around the next two lines.

Comment: James, I tried your suggestions, many thanks for taking the time to offer your suggestion. I am still receiving the same error message. Undefined is null or not an object on --  var myvalues=thisValue.split('|'); Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you are passing that becomes thisValue is null or undefined.  You can test this parameter before blindly trying to .split it (the split function works only on strings).

```
function fill(thisValue) {
    // "value" will always be a string
    var value = thisValue ? String(thisValue) : '';

    // this line will not generate an error now
    var myvalues=value.split('|');

    // but these ones might!  make sure the length of myvalues is at least 2
    if (myvalues.length >= 2) {
      $('#inputString').val(myvalues[0]);
      $('#email').val(myvalues[1]);
    }
    // this might need to go inside the above if
    window.setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
```

Comment: James, thank you very much for taking the time out of your day to list the comments as to what I am looking at! I really appreciate you showing me how to do this, as opposed to doing it for me. I made some changes based on your comments and the script is working great! Again thanks for showing me how to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fill(thisValue) {
    myvalues=thisValue.split('|');

    $('#inputString').val(myvalues[0]);
    $('#email').val(myvalues[1]);

    window.setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this post Rakesh. I have implemented your suggestion and I am receiving error messages:Error: 'undefined' is null or not an object on this line of code --   myvalues=thisValue.split('|');

Comment: What do you get for `thisValue`, can you alert or log this? paste it here.

Comment: Rakesh, if I OK the error message, both values appear in the field(s) Here is where it throws an error in the MSIE debugger tool: Line: 32
Error: 'undefined' is null or not an object and it references to myvalues=thisValue.split('|'); Thanks